# Host multiple mobile apps on one node server?

Tags: ios, node.js, mobile, centos, port

I have been configuring my CentOS VPS to host various services for mobile apps using node.js.

With all my research, I'm sure I can now manage to deploy a node.js server for one application, but how do I go about separating my services on the server that all go through port 80?

I thought about using a different port for each app, so port 3000 would be mobileApp1, port 30001 would be mobileApp2, but after reading several posts I came to the conclusion this was a bad idea. Primarily because most firewalls are configured to allow connections to port 80 and eventually I may want to create sites that utilize the same web services as the mobile clients.

I found a [site](http://nerdpress.org/2012/04/20/hosting-multiple-express-node-js-apps-on-port-80/) that recommended using a proxy like so:

```
    var http = require('http')
, httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

httpProxy.createServer({
  hostnameOnly: true,
  router: {
    //web-development.cc
    'www.my-domain.com': '127.0.0.1:3001',
    'www.my-other-domain.de' : '127.0.0.1:3002'
  }
}).listen(80);
```

How can I support various web services that may get called from either mobile apps or one of my web pages and have it all go through port 80?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use node as a proxy and have it run on port 80, routing requests based on the URL to your various node applications, or you can run a web server on port 80, and have it route requests to your node applications.  There are a lot of proxy options within node, so from here it's going to get into more opinion as to which you should use.  One option I've had success with it the web framework [Hapi](https://github.com/spumko/hapi) which Walmart has used to route requests to their application servers.  [Here's some documentation on how they used Hapi to proxy requests.](https://gist.github.com/hueniverse/7686452#api-proxying)

Another, possibly more used option is to use a web server such as [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/) or [Nginx](http://nginx.com/) on port 80 (and 443) and have it route requests to your application servers based on the URLs.  There's a lot of documentation out there on how to set this up, since this is what a *lot* of people do to route requests.  I've put together a gist to help remember how to setup a simple nginx server to route requests based on the domain to separate node applications, which you can find here: https://gist.github.com/dylants/8609050.  (Note that the gist expects SSL to be enabled on those connections, but hopefully gives you an idea.)

But at a high level, it's fine (and quite normal) to run multiple node applications on the same machine on different ports (my gist I pasted is for an environment that does this).  You can then restrict access to the outside world on those ports (say 3000, 3001, 3002, etc) and only allow access on ports 80 and 443.  Then have your web server runs on port 80 and 443, and routes the requests to those node applications running on ports 3000, 3001, etc.

The good thing about using these web servers is that they're really easy once you understand the basics, and run without much maintenance at all after that.  You may have to do a little bit of research initially, but it'll be worth it in the end.  Hope that helps :)

Comment: @dylants so let's say I have two apps running on the same server. App1 goes starts using Sync code and blocking the main thread. Does App2 get blocked as well?

Comment: @vernak2539 I'm not sure what you mean by blocking the main thread, if they are separate apps they should have separate contexts/threads.  You might want to ask a separate question so that you can provide more details, but generally speaking, separate apps don't block each other since they have separate code.